# AttributeError: 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'setter'

Tags: python

I'm using the functools.cached_property to memoize some functions.

but it seems not to be supporting setter.

for example

```
class User
  @cached_property
  def name(self):
    return self._name

  @name.setter
  def name(self, val):
    self._name = val
```

but when importing  i encountered `AttributeError: 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'setter'`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve. @cached_property is for functions that take some time to compute but whose result never or rarely changes. If the result does change you can use `del user.name` to invalidate the cache, the next call will recompute the result. However in this example, why not just use an @property?

Comment: @xjcl but there are certain use cases it does need to change, so i want to implement a setter, just like `@property` can achieve

Answer (score 4):

@cached_property is designed for immutable values. You cannot expect that this decorator will mimic all features from standard property. In python doc you can find:
"The mechanics of cached_property() are somewhat different from property(). A regular property blocks attribute writes unless a setter is defined. In contrast, a cached_property allows writes."

Comment: can you link to the relevant doc please?

Comment: Please find https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html